# Excel VBA: Hide Rows with FormulaR1C1

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to hide the rows that contain the dates of holidays. In another module, I have the command "yes" in cell R3 to activate this sub so I just need to figure out the sub. There are no errors, it just doesn't hide the rows I need it to hide. The formula I'm using works to find the holidays because it properly highlights the cells when I put it into Conditional Formatting. Code is below:

```
Sub HideHolidays()

Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, chkCol As Long, chkCommCol As Long, rowCnt As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
beginRow = 4
HolidaybeginRow = 2
endRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2017 All Districts").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<--| set 'endRow' to column A last not empty cell row index
chkCol = 1
chkCommCol = 17
chkHolCol = 18
'Set Sheets("2017 All Districts").Range(beginRow, chkCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=Match($A1,Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)"

'Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhides all rows. Subsequent code will hide relevant ones

If Cells(3, chkHolCol).Value = "Yes" Then '<--| if Q3 value is "Yes"
    For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow '<--| loop through the "limit" rows indexes
        With Cells(rowCnt, chkCol) '<--| reference current cell to be cheked
            If ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Match($A1,Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)" Then
                Application.EntireRow.Hidden
            End If
        End With
    Next
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image: SAMPLE DATA]
[image: HOLIDAYS SPREADSHEET THAT IS REFERENCED]

HIDE WEEKEND CODE:
    Sub HideWeekends()
      Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, chkCol As Long, chkCommCol As Long,     rowCnt As Long

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
beginRow = 4
endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<--| set 'endRow' to column A     last not empty cell row index
chkCol = 1
chkCommCol = 17

Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhides all rows. Subsequent code will hide relevant ones

If Cells(3, chkCommCol).Value = "Yes" Then '<--| if Q3 value is "Yes"
   For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow '<--| loop through the "limit" rows indexes
    With Cells(rowCnt, chkCol) '<--| reference current cell to be cheked
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Weekday(.Value2, vbMonday) > 5 '<--| set its corresponding Row 'Hidden' property to True if currently referenced cell has wanted color
    End With
Next
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You could try `For rowCnt = endRow To beginRow step -1` instead of `For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow` if your code doesn't hide the right rows.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and I will definitely keep that in mind if I ever have that issue; however, the problem seems to be that the code doesn't register the dates as matches with my referenced sheet (See below, along with screenshots of data I included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some issues:

- you use `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` but

  - `ActiveCell` is neither "updated" (with some `Select` statement)
  - nor has it any relation with the actual loop variable which is `Cells(rowCnt, chkCol)`
- you use `FormulaR1C1` while `"=Match($A1,Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)"` is not in a `R1C1` style
- with `ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=Match($A1,Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)"` you are comparing two `Formula` expression, while

  - the actual content of your checked cells is a real `date` (not a formula returning the `date`)
  - you want to check if the current cell content (a date) is in a given range: that you can achieve by means of `Find()` method of `Range` object or `Match()` method of `Application` object
- you're not qualifying all ranges up to their worksheet object

for all what above you may try this refactoring of your code:

**edited** to follow OP's request to *reverse* the code if "2017 All Districts" sheet "R3" cell content is "Yes"

```
Sub HideHolidays()

    Dim beginRow As Long, rowCnt As Long, chkCol As Long

    beginRow = 4
    chkCol = 1
    With Worksheets("2017 All Districts") '<--| reference your sheet
        With .Range(.Cells(beginRow, chkCol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, chkCol).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference referenced sheet 'chkCol' column from row 'beginRow' down to last not empty one
            .EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhides all referenced range rows: subsequent code will hide relevant ones if referenced sheet R3 cell isn't "Yes"
            If .Parent.Range("R3").Value <> "Yes" Then Exit Sub    '<--| exit if referenced range sheet R3 cell value isn't "Yes"
            For rowCnt = 1 To .Rows.Count '<--| loop through all referenced range cells
                .Cells(rowCnt, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = Not IsError(Application.Match(CDbl(.Cells(rowCnt, 1)), Worksheets("Holidays").Range("$B$2:$B$11"), 0)) '<--| hide current cell entire row if its content doesn't match any value in "Holidays" sheet range $B$2:$B$11
            Next
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran the code (needed to change Q3 to R3 for Holidays) and it hide every single row except for the following date: 1-Jan
2-Jan
3-Jan
16-Jan
20-Feb

Comment: since I tested my code, you should step through it and use Immediate Window to check relevant variable current values at every statement. As a head start you could check "R3" cell in "2017 All Districts" sheet is "Yes"...

Comment: R3 is a drop down with options "Yes" and "No". When you select yes, then all rows that contain a holiday date are to be hidden. When you click "No", then they unhide. In the comment in your code you stated that the code hides any rows that don't match; however, I need to hide the rows that DO match.

Comment: if you want the Sub to be triggered by any change of R3 cell content then you have to move it into a worksheet_change event handler or have this latter call it. try running the sub by itself and see if it runs properly

Comment: see edited code for hiding rows with cells matching holidays

Comment: The sub runs fine, it is just hiding the wrong rows. It hides everything that is NOT a match, but I need it to hide the rows that DO match the Holidays sheet. I am looking at the code but I can't figure out where it dictates to hide the ones that are not a match rather than the ones that do match. Also, I have the worksheet_change already set up.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it seems to work! Thank you so much for all of your help. What did you change in the code in order to fix the code?

Comment: you are welcome. To _reverse_ the condition I simply added a `Not` before `IsError()`. You may then want to mark answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you!

Comment: Last question: How do I reverse the code if I select R3 to be "No"? I have a code below that hides the weekends and it undoes the code if Q3 says No. ((I put the code in the original since I couldn't post it here))

Comment: see edited code for reversing the behavior if "R3" cell content  is "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

You should fully qualify the objects you want to work with.

```
Sub HideHolidays()

Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, chkCol As Long, chkCommCol As Long, rowCnt As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2017 All Districts")
beginRow = 4
HolidaybeginRow = 2
endRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<--| set 'endRow' to column A last not empty cell row index
chkCol = 1
chkCommCol = 17
chkHolCol = 18
'Set Sheets("2017 All Districts").Range(beginRow, chkCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=Match($A1,Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)"

'Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhides all rows. Subsequent code will hide relevant ones

If ws.Cells(3, chkHolCol).Value = "Yes" Then '<--| if Q3 value is "Yes"
    For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow '<--| loop through the "limit" rows indexes
        With ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol) '<--| reference current cell to be cheked
            If ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=Match($A1,Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)" Then
                ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden 'use the range object to hide and not application.
            End If
        End With
    Next
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for inputting the updated line. I ran the code and debugged it and it seems that the code doesn't find any matches to the Holiday Sheet. I am going to include screenshots of the code. Would you mind helping me out in finding out why the code doesn't register the matches even though it does in my Conditional Formatting?

Comment: 1) `If ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=Match($A1,Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)"` is comparing two formulas, not their returned value. 2) You are using `With ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol)` and then repating the same range reference inside the `With` block: either you don't use `With ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol)` or you don't use `ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol)` reference inside it 3) you should explicit the value you're setting `.Hidden` property to

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you write Option Explicit at the top of your code sheets so that you will be forced to declare all your variables. Actually, you had a lot of constants, and the most efficient way to declare numeric constants is by means of an enumeration. This is what I did.

```
Option Explicit

    Private Enum Num
        FirstHolidayRow = 2
        ChkRow               ' no number declared means previous + 1
        FirstRow
        chkCol = 1
        chkCommCol = 17
        ChkHolCol
    End Enum
```

Note that enums must be placed at the top of code sheets, before any procedures. Next I revised your code. Now it looks like this:-

```
Sub HideHolidays()
    ' 24 Mar 2017

    Dim WsAllDistricts As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long

    Set WsAllDistricts = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2017 All Districts")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WsAllDistricts
        '<--| set 'endRow' to column A last not empty cell row index
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With WsAllDistricts
        If .Cells(ChkRow, ChkHolCol).Value = "Yes" Then '<--| if Q3 value is "Yes"
            For R = FirstRow To LastRow '<--| loop through the "limit" rows indexes
                If InStr(1, .Cells(R, chkCol).Formula, _
                            "Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)", vbTextCompare) Then
                    .Rows(R).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next R
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It works, but I'm not sure that it does what you want it to do. The presumption is that there is only one sheet. If there is another it doesn't make its appearance in your code. Please bear in mind that you must specify the workbook to find a sheet, a sheet to find a row, and a column to find a cell. Sometimes these specifications are implicit, like a sheet knowing perfectly well to which workbook it belongs, but that isn't the case with Range("A1") which could be on any sheet. And, of course, if you wish to address the ActiveCell you must first activate a cell. All the addressing discrepancies were resolved.

There is a problem with your desire to look for the formula because the formula has the syntax `=MATCH($A9` in it, where row 9 is variable. So, there is only one formula exactly like this in your sheet. I resolved this by looking only for the match range `"Holidays!$B$2:$B$11,0)"`. If this isn't enough there are other ways of dealing with this issue with more precision.